# Making a duaa from the heart

Tags: dua

Salam, I was making duaa and it felt a lot different this time like I was actually making a connection with Allah. I started to cry whilst making duaa and after the duaa I felt relieved and a lot happier. Can someone explain to me as to why I feel like this? Jazakallah

Comment: It’s the connection between a believer’s heart and Allah. Why wouldn’t it make you happy and relieved ?

Comment: I’m not sure it’s been a long time since I felt this way when I make duaa but the feeling was so good

Comment: Good for you brother alhamdouli Lah